# Sending PUT call to set notificaton preference in Canvas API and not succeeding

Tags: curl, notifications, put, preference

I am trying to set notification preferences in Canvas (instructure) LMS using CURL. I can get all the preferences so the User and communication channel is fine. I can put some other data but not a new notification preference.  Eventually I would like to put a value for the category, but for now just trying to set one notification preference

**This command works fine - get the value of the notification preference**
curl.exe https://myschool.instructure.com/api/v1/users/33/communication_channels/38/notification_preferences/new_announcement -H "Authorization: Bearer token"

**RETURNS**

```
{
  "notification_preferences":[
    {
      "frequency":"never",
      "notification":"new_announcement",
      "category":"announcement"
    }
  ]
}
```

**This command works fine (example of a put via curl)**
curl.exe https://myschool.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/473/front_page -d wiki_page[body]=”something new” -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer token"

**This command fails - trying to put a new value for the notification preference**
curl.exe --verbose https://myschool.instructure.com/api/v1/users/33/communication_channels/38/notification_preferences/new_announcement -d notification_preferences[frequency]=”immediately” -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer token"

**ERROR in HTML:**

```
<p>
There was a problem with your last request. 
You may have tried to perform an action after a long period of inactivity. 
If that&#39;s the case, try going back, reloading the page you were working on, and resubmitting. 
If not, please let us know what you were doing when the error happened.
</p>
```

**ERROR inside the CURL RESPONSE:**
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't think there are many people here with experience with instructure, your best bet is to contact them directly: https://www.instructure.com/canvas/support-faq or https://www.instructure.com/contact-us

Comment: ...and unfortunately their official documentation does not have any curl samples: https://canvas.beta.instructure.com/doc/api/notification_preferences.html
let them know that a few samples there will be very helpful